# QRubberBand to crop image in Qt

Tags: qt

I want to be able to use `QRubberBand` to select an area of image, and then save the new selected area in a new place after cropping it.

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881989/using-qrubberband-to-crop-image-in-qt?answertab=active#tab-top) but I need to know what's `a` and `b` in `mapFormGlobal(a)` or `(b)`

```
void MainResizeWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(ui->imageLabel->underMouse()){
        myPoint = event->pos();
        rubberBand = new QRubberBand(QRubberBand::Rectangle, this);
        rubberBand->show();
    }
}

void MainResizeWindow::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    rubberBand->setGeometry(QRect(myPoint, event->pos()).normalized());
}

void MainResizeWindow::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    QPixmap OriginalPix(*ui->imageLabel->pixmap());
    double sx = ui->imageLabel->rect().width();
    double sy = ui->imageLabel->rect().height();
    sx = OriginalPix.width() / sx;
    sy = OriginalPix.height() / sy;

    QPoint a = mapToGlobal(myPoint);
    QPoint b = event->globalPos();

    a = ui->imageLabel->mapFromGlobal(a);
    b = ui->imageLabel->mapFromGlobal(b);

    a.x = int(a.x * sx);
    b.x = int(b.x * sx);
    a.y = int(a.y * sy);
    b.y = int(b.y * sy);

    QRect myRect(a, b);

 //  QPixmap OriginalPix(*ui->imageLabel->pixmap());

    QImage newImage;
    newImage = OriginalPix.toImage();


    QImage copyImage;
    copyImage = copyImage.copy(myRect);

    ui->imageLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(copyImage));
    ui->imageLabel->repaint();
}
```

I get error

```
error: 'a' was not declared in this scope
     a = ui->imageLabel->mapFromGlobal(a);
     ^
```

where it should be declared  in `mainresizewindow.h` or what is the correct way

Comment: In the answer you linked, `a` and `b` are declared immediately above the two lines you posted

Comment: but when i runn the code  
it gets me erorr 'a' was not declared in this scope a = ui->imageLabel->mapFromGlobal(a);

Comment: did you also copy the two lines `QPoint a = mapToGlobal(myPoint);
QPoint b = event->globalPos();`?

Comment: sure i put it .i edit the question with the all code

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Do you get other errors before that, like `QPoint` undeclared?

Comment: ii rearrange my code but i get new error in    a.x = int(a.x * sx);
    b.x = int(b.x * sx);
    a.y = int(a.y * sy);
    b.y = int(b.y * sy);   the error: invalid use of member function (did you forget the '()' ?)
     a.x = int(a.x * sx);
                     ^

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the mouseReleaseEvent method as follows:

```
void MainResizeWindow::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    QPixmap OriginalPix(ui->imageLabel->pixmap());
    QImage newImage;
    newImage = OriginalPix.toImage();
    QImage copyImage;
    copyImage = newImage.copy(rubberBand->geometry());
    ui->imageLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(copyImage));
    ui->imageLabel->repaint();
}
```

As soon as you release the mouse button the selection image will be cropped and shown to you in the label.

Comment: `QPixmap OriginalPix(*ui->imageLabel->pixmap());`??? 
the correct is: `QPixmap OriginalPix(ui->imageLabel->pixmap());`