# rotate Qpixmap then crop it

Tags: image, qt, rotation, qpixmap, qlabel

I am newer in QT, I make a program that rotates images in QLabel and select area to crop, my code of crop based on this code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881989/using-qrubberband-to-crop-image-in-qt) and my code of rotate is

```
           current_angle = current_angle + value;
           current_angle = current_angle % 360;
           QPixmap pixmap(original_pixmap_angle);
           QTransform rotate_disc;
           rotate_disc.rotate(current_angle);
           pixmap = pixmap.transformed(rotate_disc);
           ui->label->setPixmap(pixmap);
```

cropping worked well if I don't make the rotation, but if I make rotate then crop it failed 
any help please

Comment: What is a "crop fail"? And what is a "crop"?

Comment: when select area and crop it, the result of new image is different from the true selected area

Comment: Please, provide a code that "crops" . I don't understand what do you do.